# xen install on centos, getting invalid magic number 9090

Tags: linux, centos6, xen

I am trying to install Xen on Centos6.5 based on this tutorial (http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Xen/Xen4QuickStart), however after installing xen and running the script to edit the grub.conf, i am not able to boot into the new kernel.

I get an error stating -

invalid magic number: 9090
Error 13: Invalid or unsupported executable format

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

**Current suspicion: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Xen/Xen4QuickStart definitely not a 10 minute install for all platforms???**

History: there is a Centos Bug on this: centos.org/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=6503

I repeated a similar process:
(1) Install Centos 6.6 (Centos kernel: 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_84) from DVD1, DVD2 with Install using only the CENTOS Repo
(2) Installed Xen (Xen4CentOS kernel:3.10.56-11.el6.centos.alt.X86_64) Issuing the following commands from the centos command line (as root, warnings from readers accepted as correct from a security standpoint) To abate the security concern, no network connection existed as an offline repo would have been used but was not actually needed for the Centos minimal install.

```
yum install centos-release-xen
yum install xen
/usr/bin/grub-bootxen.sh
```

from the Xen/Centos reference: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Xen/Xen4QuickStart

I noticed that the /boot/grub/grub.conf file was non-existent and tried to reboot without it. The reference above suggests it should be there, so I am proposing that your grub.conf file was missing or incorrect because my results were similar:

```
'invalid magic number: 9090
Error 13: Invalid or unsupported executable format
Press any key to continue...'
```

So as of now I can reproduce the problem. I will be updating this as I discover what will solve it for my solution, post it with hope it fixes it for yours or others who share similar issues.

I noticed something odd, I was using a Combo USB hub and tried to reboot using the other kernel (2.6) and there were considerable failures which were squawking on the startup screen and it would not permit me to start. When I removed it I could not boot into the 3.10, but only into 2.6.

Ok, a quick find on grub.conf revealed a similar version to that shown on the reference link above in /etc. So I copied the grub.conf from /etc to /boot/grub and rebooted. But I too see similar results. The USB hub is off the system and will not be reattached, so there is something else here that needs review. I'm digging into the grub.conf file at this time...

(update) I see that there is a grub.conf file under /boot/efi/EFI/redhat. Oddly in the Centos 'bug archives' there appears to be a related resolved bug for Centos 7: bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=7242 (cannot post this as a link as my reputation is less than 10, my apologies)

Also, as this relates to magic number here are results for my type of files and magic numbers, but I have done this with vi and have some assumptions here about what I saw, so I am retrying this with the help of the other stackoverflow article which uses file-devel package LibMagic... here are the intermittent results.

```
File.x86_64                                 Magic number (if two bytes, just use first 2)        
vmlinuz-2.6.32.504.el6.x86_64               /0x8c/0x8e/0x8e/0x8e
vmlinuz-3.10.56-11.el6.centos.alt.x86_64    /0x8c/0x8e/0x8e/0x8e
```

Note: A search of '9090' on centos.org using the provided search engine for words on the site yielded no response on 12/22/14: @wiki.centos.org/Search 
There is no mention of installation problems with SELinux, even though I have set:

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

in the /etc/sysconfig/selinux file and

```
yum uninstall xen
yum install xen
/usr/bin/grub-bootxen.sh
```

No results, and no new grub file in any of the three locations listed above. /etc /boot or /boot/efi/EFI/redhat.

Comparison of the grub.conf files with other sources, show that it is reasonable. Same for the grub-bootxen.sh file based on what I could decipher from bash.

Changing the timeout in grub.conf (all I found) to 15 and removing the hiddenmenu command by #hiddenmenu, did not eliminate the '9090' error. Using: wiki.xen.org/wiki/RHEL6_Xen4_Tutorial which shows the 'kernel' modifier instead of the 'module' and changing the 'module' in front of the .img file to initrd, did not change the results.

OK. Reload.

```
1) reinstall minmum Centos
2) disable SE Linux
3) reboot
4) correct ifcfg-eth0 (remove NM and allow boot on startup) and service network restart  
5) yum import centos-release-xen (accept import of GPG key)
6) yum install xen
7) investigate what occurs with "grub-install hd0" which produces '9090' error!
```

Ok, I would have to say that the question was not well defined. It is now well defined and can be posed as a question. I will convert this info and my trials to a reasonable question to see if anyone can assist with pointers...

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. I think the issue is related to the UEFI install method. I suspect if you do a net install as you mentioned this issue should go away.